# Long exact sequence of $\ell$-adic cohomology with compact support for $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ union of two irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$, possibly not equidimensional. Assume that $X$ has only two irreducible components $X_1$ and $X_2$, and that each $X_i$ is a nonsingular complete variety. Assume further that $X_1$ and $X_2$ meet transversally at $Y := X_1 \cap X_2$. In particular, $Y$ is nonsingular, and the singular locus of $X$ consists precisely of $Y$. Let $U_i := X \setminus X_i$ denote the open complement of $X_i$. Finally, fix $\ell$ a prime different from $p$. We will write $H^i(\,\cdot\,) := H^i(\,\cdot\,,\mathbb Q_{\ell})$ for the $\ell$-adic cohomology groups of the various varieties above.

Recall the existence of the long exact sequence of cohomology with compact support given a closed subvariety of $X$ and its open complement. Let me form the following diagram.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\vdots & & \vdots \\
\downarrow & & \uparrow \\
H_c^i(U_1) & \rightarrow & H^i(X_2) \\
\downarrow & & \uparrow \\
H^i(X) & = & H^i(X) \\
\downarrow & & \uparrow \\
H^i(X_1) & \leftarrow &  H^i_c(U_2)\\ 
\downarrow & & \uparrow \\
\vdots & & \vdots
\end{array}$$

Here, the columns are the LES for the triples $(U_1,X,X_1)$ and $(U_2,X,X_2)$. The horizontal maps come from the LES for the triples $(U_1,X_2,Y)$ and $(U_2,X_1,Y)$, after noticing that $U_i = X \setminus X_i = X_{i+1} \setminus Y$.

Is this diagram commutative? Of course, I am well aware that the LES is functorial with respect to the pair $(U,Z)$ (the open subset $U$ and its closed complement $Z$), but unless I'm mistaken my question does not seem to be just an application of this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $k$-variety $\pi_Z \colon Z\longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(k)$, let's write $D(Z)$ for $D^b_c(Z,\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_l)$ whose unit object is denoted by $\mathbb{1}_Z$, then $H^i(Z) = \operatorname{Hom}_{D(k)}(\mathbb{1}_k,(\pi_Z)_*\mathbb{1}_Z[i])$ and $H^i_c(Z) = \operatorname{Hom}_{D(k)}(\mathbb{1}_k,(\pi_Z)_!\mathbb{1}_Z[i])$.

Your long exact sequences should involve cohomology with compact support. By this I mean it should be $H^i_c(U_1) \longrightarrow H^i_c(X) \longrightarrow H^i_c(X_1)$ and by properness $H^i_c(X_1) = H^i(X_1)$.

Let $v_1 \colon U_1 = X_2 \setminus Y \hookrightarrow X_2,t_2 \colon X_2 \hookrightarrow X$ be inclusions. Then the (co)unit morphisms $(t_2 \circ v_1)_!\mathbb{1}_{U_1}\to \mathbb{1}_X$, $\mathbb{1}_X \to (t_2)_!\mathbb{1}_{X_2}$ and $(v_1)_!\mathbb{1}_{U_1} \to \mathbb{1}_{X_2}$, respectively induce morphisms (simply by taking composition)

$$H^i_c(U_1) = \operatorname{Hom}_{D(k)}(\mathbb{1}_k,(\pi_{U_1})_!\mathbb{1}_{U_1}[i])  \to H^i_c(X) = \operatorname{Hom}_{D(k)}(\mathbb{1}_k,(\pi_{X})_!\mathbb{1}_{X}[i]) $$
$$H^i_c(X) = \operatorname{Hom}_{D(k)}(\mathbb{1}_k,(\pi_{X})_!\mathbb{1}_{X}[i]) \to H^i_c(X_2) = \operatorname{Hom}_{D(k)}(\mathbb{1}_k,(\pi_{X_2})_!\mathbb{1}_{X_2}[i])$$
$$H^i_c(U_1) = \operatorname{Hom}_{D(k)}(\mathbb{1}_k,(\pi_{U_1})_!\mathbb{1}_{U_1}[i]) \to H^i_c(X_2) = \operatorname{Hom}_{D(k)}(\mathbb{1}_k,(\pi_{X_2})_!\mathbb{1}_{X_2}[i])$$
Now it is necessary to have a factorization $H^i_c(U) \to H^i_c(X) \to H^i_c(X_2)$ thanks to functoriality
$$(\pi_{U_1})_!\mathbb{1}_{U_1} = (\pi_X)_!(t_2 \circ v_1)_!\mathbb{1}_{U_1} \longrightarrow (\pi_X)_!\mathbb{1}_X \to (\pi_X)_!(t_2)_!\mathbb{1}_{X_2}= (\pi_{X_2})_!\mathbb{1}_{X_2}.$$

Comment: Dear Alexey, let me apologize for the delay. Thank you very much for your answer! The method of reasoning that you explained to me in this question and the previous one is very enlightning, and I was able to deal with other similar situations by myself now. I learned a lot, so thanks a lot!